# How do I get a button to not change sizes when text is added?

Tags: css

[image]

I made this set of buttons for a tic tac toe game to practice React. I want all the boxes to make up a square. However, when text is added, the size of the box changes.

While I am at it, how do I get the font size to fill up a certain percentage of the box? Like 80%.

My CSS

```
    .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.cell {
    font-size: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.cell:nth-child(3n) {

}

#playGrid {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 30vw;
}
```

Comment: Hello, please add some code :)

Comment: What are you using for making the grid? I suggest you use CSS-Grid

Comment: @jsv wow. Sorry about that. It is added.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `button` element and not an anchor styled to look like a button, simply specifying a fixed width and height would solve the problem.

If it is an anchor tag styled to look like a button then you'll have to set its display property to `inline-block` first

You can also use:

```
 min-width: 50px;
 min-height: 50px;
```

Keep in mind that if you have a lot of content the text will overflow but in your case, it's only going to be one letter (either X or O)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is assign a fixed value to the width and height of your buttons, for example in the case that `.cell` is the class for your tik-tak-toe button game you could do:

```
.cell {
   font-size: 2rem;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   /* add this */
   width: 50px; /* this could be any value that you want */
   height: 50px; /* the same value */
}
```